# Android: ListFragment loading items twice

Tags: android, android-listfragment

Here is the situation.

i am currently using a list fragment in one of my tabs using action bar. have 3 tabs; tab1, tab2, tab3.. listfragment is on tab2 and just some Fragment on tab1, so when i start my app defualt is ont tab1.. and when i click on tab2 it loads something from the database, **TAKE NOTE HAVE ONLY ONE ROW CURRENTLY STORED IN DATABASE** so when i click back on tab1 den after clicked again on tab2 suddenly my list has already two items of the same values, it just got duplicated or loaded twice.. and i have only 1 entry on my database.

how do i prevent my fragment to load the list twice, i mean when i load this listfragment the second time around it will just load what is on the db and removes that previous value on listFragment. my theory on this problem is that, the first time i clicked tab2 its ok, when i click tab1 den after tab2, the previous items weren't deleted and when the fragment is loaded it is appended to the previous item..

how do i prevent this from happening..

[image]

Here is a sample picture, don't mind the UI flaws but just imagine that entry got doubled from loading the fragment twice.

This is a snippet on onActivityCreated

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        loadPatientList(0);
    }
```

This is my loadPatientList()

```
Cursor c = dbHelper.retrieveAllData(PATIENT_TABLE);
c.moveToFirst();       
while(!c.isAfterLast())
{
    Patients p = new Patients();
    Log.d("patient id",Integer.toString(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"))));
    p.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    p.setFname(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstname")));
    p.setMi(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("middlename")));
    p.setLname(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastname")));
    p.setAddr(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")));
    p.setHosp_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("hosp_name")));
    p.setHosp_room(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("hosp_room")));
    p.setAge(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("age")));
    p.setMed_history(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("med_history")));
    p.setPat_status(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("status")));
    patient_list.add(p);

    c.moveToNext();
}

dbHelper.close();

Collections.sort(patient_list, new Comparator<Patients>() {
   public int compare(Patients o1, Patients o2) {
      return o1.getLname().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getLname());
   }
});

PatientAdapter patientListAdapter = new PatientAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.patient_list_item_fragment, patient_list);
setListAdapter(patientListAdapter);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Comment: NOTE by loading twice, i mean when i first click tab2 (after starting the app) <-- its okey and when i click back tab1 den tab2 thats what i mean loaded twice..

Comment: post relevant snippet of code

Comment: yep done, sorry for that forgot to post it

Comment: the issue is related to patient_list. Post where  you fill up patient_list

Comment: Is patient_list a static field?

Comment: nope just an ordinary class member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onActivityCreated()
```

is called when you resume the "`PatientFragment`". Since `List`, allows duplicate, everytime you go back to "`PatientFragment`", you fill up `patient_list` again and again. Just before enter the `while` cycle, try to clear your `patient_list`, removing all the elements (`List` should be have the `clear()` method).

Comment: so basically when the fragment got replaced, its state is paused? not entirely destroyed or something?

Comment: replace should remvoe the fragment. How do you replace the fragment. show the code

Comment: yep this helps. clearing the arraylist before loading it with values, for remove the fragments, i just called ft.remove(frag) where ft is the fragmenttransaction.  btw its already working tnx a lot man!

Comment: sir i just want to clarify something, when a fragment got remove from its container, what is its current state? is it paused? or destroyed?

Comment: you can not say for sure. GC can collect it only if there is no live reference to the fragment.